# RBAC на уровне данных

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация

Всем привет!
В yii2 RBAC реализован на уровне контроллеров/экшенов, а существует ли такая возможность для данных?
Например: в таблице posts есть посты, каждый из которых привязан к конкретному пользователю. Мне нужно чтобы пользователь U1 не имел доступа к постам пользователя U2, как такое реализовывается в yii?
В каждом экшене проверять ID пользователей? Ок, с одной ролью проблем нет, но что если ролей несколько moderator/admin/editor?

Comment: https://goo.gl/wq3gs4
есть конечно, создаешь roles, permissions и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно создать правило и привязать к роли , где будет валидироваться показ
я нашел данную информацию в этом видео 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTRUjYqZK2c&t=51s
там пример на редактировании постов. вам нужно уловить суть, напишите как вам понравится